# move data from filesystem to database

Tags: php, filesystems

I need to move data from filesystem to database

main folder is `home` with files and subfolders on various levels

my idea is to loop trough all folders using `DirectoryIterator` - and get filename and content of each file inside the current folder

this code shows Fatal error:

`Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: DirectoryIterator... on line 53`

I think the problem is actually with line `72` but all my attempts are unsuccessful

Please help

```
function go($path){
  global $db;
  $it = new DirectoryIterator($path); // line 53
  foreach ($it as $a){
    if ($a->isDot()){continue;}
        if($a->isDir()){
      $fopath = $it->getPathname();
            $foname = $a->getFilename();
            $foid = uniqid();
            $sq = "insert into nts (id, what, title) values (:aid, :awhat, :atitle)";
            $st = $db->prepare($sq);
            $st->execute([":aid" => $foid, ":awhat" => 'fo', ":atitle" => $foname]);
            $arr = array_filter(glob($fopath . "/*"), 'is_file');
            foreach($arr as $el){
                $fiid = uniqid();
                $finame = basename($el, '.txt');
                $story = file_get_contents($el);
                $sq = "insert into nts (id, what, par, title, story) values (:aid, :awhat, :apar, :atitle, :astory)";
                $st = $db->prepare($sq);
                $st->execute([":aid" => $fiid, ":awhat" => 'fi', ":apar" => $foid, ":atitle" => $finame, ":astory" => $story]);
            }
            go("{$path}{$a->getPathname()}/");  // line 72
        }
  }
}}
    }
 
go("home/");
```

Comment: wtf?! why would you do / need that? just copy the folder & reference the files with the path to them.

Comment: The exception is coming from the DirectoryIterator constructor. So you must be feeding it an invalid path at some point. Make a debug output of that `"{$path}{$a->getPathname()}/"` value (or one of `$path` at the very beginning of the function), and see what that actually contains.